# IFNULL not working like I want to

Tags: mysql, sql, ifnull

I have two DATE-fields (PublishFrom, PublishTo) that are nullable.
I am trying to get the records with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblNews 
    WHERE Publish = 1 
    AND IFNULL(PublishFrom, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= "2015-03-13" 
    AND IFNULL(PublishTo, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= "2015-03-13" 
    ORDER BY DateCreated DESC'
```

The meaning is that if the value of (one of) these fields is null, it is replaced by the value of yesterday and/off tomorrow so that the entry is always shown.

Right now I see only the posts where PublishFrom and/or PublishTo is not null. How come?

Answer (score 2):

Using `CURDATE() + 1` or `- 1` will convert `CURDATE` and screw up the comparison.  [Instead use `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` (or `- INTERVAL 1 DAY`)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: this works but does not give me the solution to the problem where only records are shown where PublishFrom and/or PublishTo is not null

Comment: `SELECT IFNULL(NULL, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= "2015-03-13" AND IFNULL(NULL, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= "2015-03-13"` returns `TRUE` so maybe `Publish` does not equal `1`?  OR maybe I just don't understand your question

Comment: Publish does equal 1 for all records. For some reason with this query the records where PublishFrom AND PublishTo are null, are not selected

Comment: on sqlfiddle it works perfectly, on my own NAS-server and on my online domain I get an empty result...

Comment: @BFlyDesign could have to do with the MySQL version -- make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use explicit logic?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNews 
WHERE Publish = 1  AND
     (PublishFrom <= '2015-03-13' OR PublishFrom IS NULL) AND
     (PublishTo >= '2015-03-13' OR PublishTo IS NULL)
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
```